# How can I check if string input is a number?

Tags: python, input, types

How do I check if a user's string input is a number (e.g., `-1`, `0`, `1`, etc.)?

```
user_input = input("Enter something:")

if type(user_input) == int:
    print("Is a number")
else:
    print("Not a number")
```

The above won't work since `input` always returns a string.

Comment: I don't know whether in "input always returns strings", "returns" is correct.

Comment: it looks like you're using python 3.x in which case yes `input` always returns strings.  See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: Oh yes, I'm aware of that, hence the question, I was just didn't know if the word return was correct.

Comment: ah, then yes the term "returns" is precisely the correct term!

Comment: @Trufa `if type(eval(user_input)) == int:` this might work.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132078/8321339

Comment: The solution very much depends on what exactly you mean by "etc".

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Simply try converting it to an int and then bailing out if it doesn't work.

```
try:
    val = int(userInput)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

See [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) in the official tutorial.

Comment: use `val = int(str(userInput))` if you want only integer values, not floats

Comment: This will also not work for Boolean as `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`

Answer (score 111):

Apparently this will not work for negative values, but it will for positive numbers.

Use `isdigit()`

```
if userinput.isdigit():
    #do stuff
```

Comment: "-1".isdigit() == False

Comment: I don't believe so, Llopis.  I kind of jumped the gun answering questions before I knew enough back when I gave this answer.  I would do the same as Daniel DiPaolo's answer for the int, but use float() instead of int().

Comment: Negative numbers and floats return false because '-' and '.'  are not digits.  The isdigit() function checks if every character in the string is between '0' and '9'.

Comment: Use `isdecimal` not `isdigit` because `isdigit` is an unsafe test that recognises characters like unicode power-of-2, ² , as a digit that can not be converted to integers.

Answer (score 58):

The method [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) will do the job:

```
>>>a = '123'
>>>a.isnumeric()
True
```

But remember:

```
>>>a = '-1'
>>>a.isnumeric()
False
```

`isnumeric()` returns `True` if **all** characters in the string are numeric characters, and there is at least one character.

So negative numbers are not accepted.

Comment: Worth noting that in Python 2.7 this only works for unicode strings. A non-unicode string (`"123456".isnumeric()`) yields `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`, while `U"12345".numeric()` = `True`

Comment: Also, there are some edge cases where this doesn't work. Take `a = '\U0001f10a'`. `a.isnumeric()` is True, but `int(a)` raises a ValueError.

Comment: `'3.3'.isnumeric()` is `False`

Answer (score 26):

For Python 3 the following will work.

```
userInput = 0
while True:
  try:
     userInput = int(input("Enter something: "))       
  except ValueError:
     print("Not an integer!")
     continue
  else:
     print("Yes an integer!")
     break
```

Answer (score 12):

EDITED:
You could also use this below code to find out if its a number or also a negative

```
import re
num_format = re.compile("^[\-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$")
isnumber = re.match(num_format,givennumber)
if isnumber:
    print "given string is number"
```

you could also change your format to your specific requirement.
I am seeing this post a little too late.but hope this helps other persons who are looking for answers :) .  let me know if anythings wrong in the given code.

Comment: This will check if there is a numeric (float, int, etc) within the string.  However, if there is more than just the numeric, it will still return a result.  For example: "1.2 Gbps" will return a false positive.  This may or may not be useful to some people.

Comment: Also note: for anyone now looking, my original comment is no longer valid.  :P  Thanks for the update @karthik27!

Answer (score 9):

If you specifically need an int or float, you could try "is not int" or "is not float":

```
user_input = ''
while user_input is not int:
    try:
        user_input = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid number: ')

print('You entered {}'.format(user_input))
```

If you only need to work with ints, then the most elegant solution I've seen is the ".isdigit()" method:

```
a = ''
while a.isdigit() == False:
    a = input('Enter a number: ')

print('You entered {}'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 6):

Works fine for check if an **input** is
   a positive Integer AND in a specific range

```
def checkIntValue():
    '''Works fine for check if an **input** is
   a positive Integer AND in a specific range'''
    maxValue = 20
    while True:
        try:
            intTarget = int(input('Your number ?'))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            if intTarget < 1 or intTarget > maxValue:
                continue
            else:
                return (intTarget)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend this, @karthik27, for negative numbers

```
import re
num_format = re.compile(r'^\-?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*')
```

Then do whatever you want with that regular expression, match(), findall() etc

Comment: good idea. clean and practical. Although it needs some changes for specific cases, say it matches 3.4.5 at the moment too

Comment: why not just: `num_format = re.compile(r'^\-?[1-9]+\.?[0-9]*')`

Comment: instead just convert to float

Answer (score 5):

The most elegant solutions would be the already proposed,

```
a = 123
bool_a = a.isnumeric()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work neither for negative integers nor for general float values of a. If your point is to check if 'a' is a generic number beyond integers, I'd suggest the following one, which works for every kind of float and integer :). Here is the test:

```
def isanumber(a):

    try:
        float(repr(a))
        bool_a = True
    except:
        bool_a = False

    return bool_a


a = 1 # Integer
isanumber(a)
>>> True

a = -2.5982347892 # General float
isanumber(a)
>>> True

a = '1' # Actually a string
isanumber(a)
>>> False
```

Comment: This will return a `float`, rather than a `bool`, if the conversion doesn't fail.

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker you are right :) Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

**natural**: [0, 1, 2 ... ∞]

Python 2

```
it_is = unicode(user_input).isnumeric()
```

Python 3

```
it_is = str(user_input).isnumeric()
```

**integer**: [-∞, .., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ∞]

```
try:
    int(user_input)
    it_is = True
except ValueError:
    it_is = False
```

**float**: [-∞, .., -2, -1.0...1, -1, -0.0...1, 0, 0.0...1, ..., 1, 1.0...1,
..., ∞]

```
try:
    float(user_input)
    it_is = True
except ValueError:
    it_is = False
```

Comment: I'd like to know what is wrong with this answer, if you don't mind. There may be better ways to perform this task that I'm willing to know

Comment: It's not wrong. People are just not understanding your stated conditions.

Answer (score 4):

This solution will accept only integers and nothing but integers.

```
def is_number(s):
    while s.isdigit() == False:
        s = raw_input("Enter only numbers: ")
    return int(s)


# Your program starts here    
user_input = is_number(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works with any number, including a fraction:

```
import fractions

def isnumber(s):
   try:
     float(s)
     return True
   except ValueError:
     try: 
       Fraction(s)
       return True
     except ValueError: 
       return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the isdigit() method for strings.
In this case, as you said the input is always a string:

```
    user_input = input("Enter something:")
    if user_input.isdigit():
        print("Is a number")
    else:
        print("Not a number")
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not divide the input by a number? This way works with everything. Negatives, floats, and negative floats. Also Blank spaces and zero.

```
numList = [499, -486, 0.1255468, -0.21554, 'a', "this", "long string here", "455 street area", 0, ""]

for item in numList:

    try:
        print (item / 2) #You can divide by any number really, except zero
    except:
        print "Not A Number: " + item
```

Result:

```
249
-243
0.0627734
-0.10777
Not A Number: a
Not A Number: this
Not A Number: long string here
Not A Number: 455 street area
0
Not A Number:
```

Comment: This only works because your numbers here are numeric types. An input of "8" (type str) would be "Not A Number."

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late but its to help anyone else that had to spend 6 hours trying to figure this out. (thats what I did):

This works flawlessly: (checks if any letter is in the input/checks if input is either integer or float)

```
a=(raw_input("Amount:"))

try:
    int(a)
except ValueError:
    try:
        float(a)
    except ValueError:
        print "This is not a number"
        a=0


if a==0:
    a=0
else:
    print a
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you input `0`, one of the examples specifically mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that checks input for INT and RANGE.  Here, returns 'True' if input is integer between 1-100, 'False' otherwise

```
def validate(userInput):

    try:
        val = int(userInput)
        if val > 0 and val < 101:
            valid = True
        else:
            valid = False

    except Exception:
        valid = False

    return valid
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is an old question, and the accepted answer seems to be pretty good.  Are you sure that you have something new to add?

Comment: I thought it was a slight improvement: no less efficient while avoiding the nested if-else.  I'm new here, if the answer hurts the community no hard feels if it's removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to evaluate floats, and you wanted to accept `NaN`s as input but not other strings like `'abc'`, you could do the following:

```
def isnumber(x):
    import numpy
    try:
        return type(numpy.float(x)) == float
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a different approach I thought I'd share. Start with creating a valid range:

```
valid = [str(i) for i in range(-10,11)] #  ["-10","-9...."10"]
```

Now ask for a number and if not in list continue asking:

```
p = input("Enter a number: ")

while p not in valid:
    p = input("Not valid. Try to enter a number again: ")
```

Lastly convert to int (which will work because list only contains integers as strings:

```
p = int(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into problems this morning with users being able to enter non-integer responses to my specific request for an integer.

This was the solution that ended up working well for me to force an answer I wanted:

```
player_number = 0
while player_number != 1 and player_number !=2:
    player_number = raw_input("Are you Player 1 or 2? ")
    try:
        player_number = int(player_number)
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter '1' or '2'..."
```

I would get exceptions before even reaching the try: statement when I used

```
player_number = int(raw_input("Are you Player 1 or 2? ")
```

and the user entered "J" or any other non-integer character.  It worked out best to take it as raw input, check to see if that raw input could be converted to an integer, and then convert it afterward.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to only catch the exceptions you're handling. In this case it'd be `ValueError`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I've edited the solution to include that feedback.  That was my first ever SO solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    b1=input('Type a number:')
    try:
        a1=int(b1)
    except ValueError:
        print ('"%(a1)s" is not a number. Try again.' %{'a1':b1})       
    else:
        print ('You typed "{}".'.format(a1))
        break
```

This makes a loop to check whether input is an integer or not, result would look like below:

```
>>> %Run 1.1.py
Type a number:d
"d" is not a number. Try again.
Type a number:
>>> %Run 1.1.py
Type a number:4
You typed 4.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It worked for me even if I input negative numbers.

```
def length(s):
    return len(s)

s = input("Enter the string: ")
try:
    if (type(int(s))) == int:
        print("You input an integer")

except ValueError:
    print("it is a string with length " + str(length(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
print(user_input.isnumeric())
```

This checks if the string has *only* numbers in it and has at least a length of 1.
However, if you try isnumeric with a string with a negative number in it, isnumeric will return `False`.

Now this is a solution that works for both negative and positive numbers

```
try:
    user_input = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    process_non_numeric_user_input()  # user_input is not a numeric string!
else:
    process_user_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not doing a simple thing in one line is not Pythonic.

A version without `try..except`, using a regex match:

Code:

```py
import re

if re.match('[-+]?\d+$', the_str):
  # Is integer
```

Test:

```py
>>> import re
>>> def test(s): return bool(re.match('[-+]?\d+$', s))

>>> test('0')
True
>>> test('1')
True
>>> test('-1')
True

>>> test('-0')
True
>>> test('+0')
True
>>> test('+1')
True


>>> test('-1-1')
False
>>> test('+1+1')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's so far only two answers that handle negatives and decimals (the [try... except answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424750/3038828) and the [regex one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457619/3038828)?).  Found a third answer somewhere a while back somewhere (tried searching for it, but no success) that uses explicit direct checking of each character rather than a full regex.

Looks like it is still quite a lot slower than the try/exceptions method, but if you don't want to mess with those, some use cases may be better compared to regex when doing heavy usage, particularly if some numbers are short/non-negative:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
```

On Python 3.10 on Windows shows representative results for me:

**Explicitly check each character**:

```
>>> print(timeit('text="1234"; z=text[0]; (z.isdigit() or z == "-" or z == ".") and all(character.isdigit() or character == "." for character in text[1:])'))
0.5673831000458449
>>> print(timeit('text="-4089175.25"; z=text[0]; (z.isdigit() or z == "-" or z == ".") and all(character.isdigit() or character == "." for character in text[1:])'))
1.0832774000009522
>>> print(timeit('text="-97271851234.28975232364"; z=text[0]; (z.isdigit() or z == "-" or z == ".") and all(character.isdigit() or character == "." for character in text[1:])'))
1.9836419000057504
```

A lot slower than the **try/except**:

```
>>> def exception_try(string):
...   try:
...     return type(float(string)) == int
...   except:
...     return false

>>> print(timeit('text="1234"; exception_try(text)', "from __main__ import exception_try"))
0.22721579996868968
>>> print(timeit('text="-4089175.25"; exception_try(text)', "from __main__ import exception_try"))
0.2409859000472352
>>> print(timeit('text="-97271851234.28975232364"; exception_try(text)', "from __main__ import exception_try"))
0.45190039998851717
```

But a fair bit quicker than **regex**, unless you have an extremely long string?

```
>>> print(timeit('import re'))
0.08660140004940331
```

(In case you're using it already)... and then:

```
>>> print(timeit('text="1234"; import re; num_format = re.compile("^[\-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"); re.match(num_format,text)'))
1.3882658999646083
>>> print(timeit('text="-4089175.25"; import re; num_format = re.compile("^[\-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"); re.match(num_format,text)'))
1.4007637000177056
>>> print(timeit('text="-97271851234.28975232364"; import re; num_format = re.compile("^[\-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$"); re.match(num_format,text)'))
1.4191589000402018
```

None are close to the simplest **isdecimal**, but that of course won't catch the negatives...

```
>>> print(timeit('text="1234"; text.isdecimal()'))
0.04747540003154427
```

Always good to have options depending on needs?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some [Python libraries](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py) use assertions to make sure that the value supplied by the programmer-user is a number.

Sometimes it's good to see an example 'from the wild'. Using `assert`/`isinstance`:

```
def check_port(port):
    assert isinstance(port, int), 'PORT is not a number'
    assert port >= 0, 'PORT < 0 ({0})'.format(port)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
a= input("Choose the option\n")

if(int(a)):
    print (a);
else:
    print("Try Again")
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. Also, `a is int` will never evaluate to `True`.

Comment: thanks @N.Wouda for your help , i have made the changes,check this

Comment: Are you sure that your answer is actually contributing something new to this question?

Comment: @N.Wouda actually I'm in a learning stage and trying to help others, so they don't get stuck in such basic problems.

Comment: That is quite commendable, don't get me wrong. But this particular question seems like it was already well-covered by the other answers, so it might be more productive to answer questions that do not yet have good anwers!

Comment: If 'a' is a string, int(a) throws an exception and the 'else' branch never gets called.  Tested in python 2 & 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can type:

```
user_input = input("Enter something: ")

if type(user_input) == int:
    print(user_input, "Is a number")
else:
    print("Not a number")
  
try:
    val = int(user_input)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not an int!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Checking for `Decimal` type:

```
import decimal
isinstance(x, decimal.Decimal)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is based on inspiration from an answer. I defined a function as below. It looks like it’s working fine.

```
def isanumber(inp):
    try:
        val = int(inp)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        try:
            val = float(inp)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Answer (score -4):

```
a=10

isinstance(a,int)  #True

b='abc'

isinstance(b,int)  #False
```