# Preventing alphabetical input

Tags: python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - How to check if input is a number (given that input always returns strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number-given-that-input-always-returns-stri)

I need to check a input and send a error message if it's not numerical. How would i do this the best way? Cant seem to find any other posts about it thou i'm shure someone must have asked this question before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if not value.isdigit():
     raise ValueError("Input must be numeric")
```

@TokenMacGuy's solution is better if you're getting your input from `raw_input()`, but otherwise this works.

If you want to loop until you get proper input rather than raise an error, try this:

```
value = input("Input: ")
while not value.isdigit():
    input("Input must be numeric, please reenter: ")
```

Comment: I'm using input(), but the thing is i need the message to be something like "Input must be numeric, please reenter: "

Comment: @Sergei, What are you going to do if it's numeric? Convert it to a number? If so, don't check, just do the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

edit:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         result = int(raw_input("Enter a Number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Input must be a number"
... 
Enter a Number: abc
Input must be a number
Enter a Number: def
Input must be a number
Enter a Number: 123
>>> result
123
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("> Please enter a number:")
    try:
        n = float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

The isdigit function can be used to test if a string is all digits and is not empty:

```
val = '255'
val.isdigit()
```