# local variable referenced before assignment with try and except statement

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm having some issues with the try and except statements, I have an entry widget that takes input in strings but I have code which converts it to a integer later, problem is if the user inputs something like text it throws an error like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ppppwn3d/workspace/Python/JailBreakBob/JailBreakBob.py", line 157, in buttonclick_gamescreen
    entryx = int(e1.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

So I wanted to hide the error with the try and except statements but I now get another error message.

This is what it looks like in the code.

```
    while pressed == 8 :
        try:
            entryx = int(e1.get())
            entryy = int(e2.get())
        except ValueError:
            print("text")

        answerx = answerlistx[randomimage]
        answery = answerlisty[randomimage]
    
        if entryx == answerx and entryy == answery
            canvas.delete(images)
            randomimage = random.randrange(0,49+1)
            scorecounter = scorecounter + 1
            game = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[randomimage])
            images = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game, anchor = NW)
            e1.delete(0, END)   
            e2.delete(0, END)
            pressed = ''
        if entryx > 10 or entryx < -10 or entryy > 10 or entryy < -10 :
            wrong = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = outside, anchor = NW)
            e1.delete(0, END)   
            e2.delete(0, END)
            pressed = ''
        else:
            wrong = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = incorrect, anchor = NW)
            e1.delete(0, END)   
            e2.delete(0, END)
            pressed = ''
```

The new error message:

```
text
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ppppwn3d/workspace/Python/JailBreakBob/JailBreakBob.py", line 165, in buttonclick_gamescreen
    if entryx == answerx and entryy == answery:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'entryx' referenced before assignment
```

I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

To add to [@alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18170726/2392038), I would rather modify the program like so:

```
    entryx, entryy = 0, 0
    try:
        entryx = int(e1.get())
        entryy = int(e2.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("text")
```

Basically, what the error means is that in case of an error, `entryx, entryy` never get assigned anything, but still get referenced later in the `if..else` check.

It's best to have default values for the variables outside of the `try..except` block.

Answer (score 10):

If there is an exception in your `try/except` block, there wouldn't be `entryx` and `entryy` variables defined in the scope.

You should either throw and error and exit the program or assign `entryx` and `entryy` default values in the `except` block.

Also, you can make a while loop until the user enters an integer like it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754600/771848).

Answer (score 2):

I would initialise answerx, answery with None before try block starts.

Answer (score 0):

you can see 'text' message.
so, exception was raised and entryx wasn't initialized.
that's why you've got:

```
local variable 'entryx' referenced before assignment
```