# Python: Checking whether or not a variable is a int (using while loop)

Tags: python-3.x

just need a little help. Starting out doing python, trying to create a high score program and I want to say while score is not equal to an integer then ask user to input score.

For example (this doesn't work)

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
score = None
while score != int(score):
    score = input("Enter your score: ")
print("congratz it worked genius")
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number-given-that-input-always-returns-stri

Comment: 1. Your score remains a string so it can never equal an integer so you can never get out of your loop. 2. int(score) raises ValueError for any string which is not containing an integer, so your bad inputs will result an exception. Check Nicolas' answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
 while True:
    try:
        score = int(input("Enter your score: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Int, please.")
```

Comment: Why does the question code not recognize an input even if it IS an int?