# Accept an input as a word and not an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, words

How to make word inputs in Python
I want to be able to have the computer to ask a question to the user like

```
test = int(input('This only takes a number as an answer'))
```

I want to be able to have 'test' not be a number, rather a word, or letter.

Comment: Can that helps? [Python - How to check if input is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number-given-that-input-always-returns-stri).

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `int` call!  **That** is what makes the statement accept integer numbers only.

I.e, use:

```
test = input('This takes any string as an answer')
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the type cast to `int`

```
test = input('This only takes a word as an answer :')
```

A demo

```
>>> test = input('This only takes a word as an answer :')
This only takes a word as an answer :word
>>> test
'word'
```

Note - From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

Therefore `input` automatically converts it to a `str` and there is no need of any explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
test = str(input('This only takes a string as an answer:  '))
```

BUT

Because Python works with String by default, actually you don't need any casting like `int` or `str`

Also, if you were using version prior to 3.x, it would be `raw_input` instead of `input`. Since your solution seem to have been accepting `input`, I can be safe assuming that your Python is OK.
    test = input('This only takes a string as an answer')

Answer (score 0):

```
 test = input("This only takes a number as an answer")
 test = raw_input("This only takes a number as an answer")
```

Either one should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2.7, just use raw_input function.

```
test = raw_input('This only takes a string as an answer:  ')
```

I.e.:

```
>>> test = raw_input('This only takes a string as an answer:  ')
This only takes a string as an answer:  2.5
>>> type (test)
<type 'str'>
```

If you use input, you can have only a number:
Right input:

```
>>> test = input('This only takes a number as an answer:  ')
This only takes a string as an answer:  2.5
>>> type (test)
<type 'float'>
```

Wrong input:

```
>>> test = input('This only takes a number as an answer:  ')
This only takes a number as an answer:  word
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```