# Beginner, Python, if statement

Tags: python

```
num=float(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
if num <0:
    print "-"
elif num>0:
    print "+"
else:
    print "0"
```

this is a simple example from one book. It works fine, but I have a question,
how to make that this program would see that I'm entering a letter instead of a number? It works just fine if I'm using numbers, but if I'm entering a letter, the program crashes. I understand that when a program gets a raw input, it needs to check if it is a number or another symbol, but I just don't know what the simplest solution would be?

Answer (score 0):

---

### **Method 1:**

---

Try to check if input is a number. This will work for both negative and positive numbers, but not for numbers like `1.1`, `1.2`, etc:

```
try:
   val = int(userInput)
   #code here
except ValueError:
   print("That's not an int!")
```

---

### **Method 2:**

---

Using an if-statement alone you could use the `isdigit()` function.
However, this will not work for negative numbers as for example `-1` will return `False`.

```
if userInput.isdigit():
    #your code here
else:
    Print("Not a digit")
```

---

### **Method 3:**

---

Here is another method to check if given `string` is a number:

```
import re
num_format = re.compile("^[\-]?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$")
isnumber = re.match(num_format,givennumber)
if isnumber:
    print("Given string is number")
else:
    print("Given string is not a number")
```

Also, try to include a log with the error next time, and add some more tags for visibility like `integer`, `string` and `if-statement`. :)

---

Source:
[How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number-given-that-input-always-returns-stri)

Answer (score 0):

```
num=raw_input('Enter a number: ')
if num is float:
    num = float(num)
    if num <0:
        print "-"
    elif num>0:
        print "+"
    else:
        print "0"
else:
    #do something
```

use 'is' to judge whether input value is float or not

Answer (score -2):

Use some simple string methods like below:

```
>>> s = '1234'
>>> s.isdigit()
True
>>>s = 'abd'
>>> s.isdigit()
False
>>> s = 'abc123'
>>> s.isdigit()
False
```

Comment: How about `'12.345'.isdigit()`?

Comment: Yeah! Obviously it gives False.