# Detect if input is a alphabet in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, input

Hello this is part of my code I'm working on. I wanted to know if there was a way to detect if the input typed is an alphabet and give a response. I need to subtracted the time so I converted it to a int but if anything other than a int is type if gives me an error.

```
def Continue():
    time = int(input("What time is it?: "))
    if time > 12:
        print ("I'm sorry, just the hour, I don't need anymore than that.")
        Continue()
    else:
        print ("It's %d" % time + "?!")
        time = time - 1
        print ("I'm late!\nI'm sorry I have to go!\nI'm sure your leg is fine just walk it off!")
        print ("I was suppose to be there at %d" % time, "I'm an hour late!")
```

Comment: An alphabet? You mean like the Greek alphabet? I guess you meant a letter of the alphabet, right?

Comment: Usually what I do is try to catch the exception raised by `int(...)` when you try to convert its argument to an int. You will no for sure that the input cannot be an int. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number or better https://www.google.com/#q=python+check+if+input+is+integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
def Continue():
    try:
        time = int(input("What time is it?: "))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input.')
        print('Please enter a number between 1 and 12.')
        Continue()
    if time > 12:
        print("I'm sorry, just the hour, I don't need anymore than that.")
        Continue()
    else:
        print("It's %d" % time + "?!")
        time = time - 1
        print ("I'm late!\nI'm sorry I have to go!\nI'm sure your leg is fine just walk it off!")
        print ("I was suppose to be there at %d" % time, "I'm an hour late!")
```

You can use a `try`-`except` statement. Python will raise an `ValueError` if the conversion into an integer fails. In this case, you catch the exception with `except`, tell the user that the input was wrong, and call your function again.

Comment: Ah thank you, it worked perfect and I learned something new I learn something new!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to not cast the input as an int immediately, but create an if else statement which checks if the input is a number or not. If it is a number, then you can cast the variable as an int.