# Python input processing when input is a float or string

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I was hoping someone could help or hint to where I'm going wrong with this Python homework assignment:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
if number == int or float:
    print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
elif number != int or float:
    print("This is not a valid number")
```

It runs fine with a whole number, but not with a float or a string. I think it's because number is set to look for an integer, but I'm not sure what to substitute that with in order to make it work.

Comment: what error do you come across?

Comment: Take a look at this question for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number

Comment: FInal answer:

number = input("Enter a number")

try:
    number = int(number)
    print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
except ValueError:
    try:
        number = float(number)
        print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
    except ValueError:
        print("This isn't an integer or float")

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [try... except... else](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block:

```
try:
    number = float(input("Enter a number"))
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a valid number")
else:
    print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
```

Comment: I wound up extrapolating on this to get my final answer, so thanks pzp. This is what my final code looks like:

number = input("Enter a number")

try:
    number = int(number)
    print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
except ValueError:
    try:
        number = float(number)
        print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
    except ValueError:
        print("This isn't an integer or float")

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap around input around a `try ... except`.

```
something = input()

try:
    something = int(something)
except:
    print("not an int")
```

Comment: Won't your `if` always return `true`? Because you check if `number` is an `int` right after casting it as an `int`.

Comment: thats what the user is doing

Answer (score 0):

Can you just replace the int with a float? like this:
"number = float(input("Enter a number"))"

I think it solves your problem. Anyway we could use a little more description.

Good luck!

Comment: wouldn't this throw a `ValueError` if user passes a string eg. "hello"

Comment: Yeah i didn't get it. He wants to do what python already does? Because python throws a "not a number" error when a string is passed..



If so i think try... except would be the solution


Anyway, here's a solution with try... except



    try:
        number = float(input("Enter a number"))
        print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
    except:
        print("This is not a valid number")

Comment: maybe he wants to like sanitize the user's input. like if the user sends something other than a int or a float then the program shouldnt break and rather show an error and ask again.

Comment: yes, i'm struggling with the markdown editing here  
I made a code that catches the error:    
    try:
        number = float(input("Enter a number"))
        print(number * number, number * number * number, number ** 4)
    except:
        print("This is not a valid number")  
I hope you can read this.