# Is there a way to input a decimal into a expected integer string

Tags: python, python-2.7

With my basic interest calculator I keep getting the error

```
 r = int(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.52'
```

the numbers I am using are principal of 20,000
Rate of 52% (.052 is what I put in)
compoundings are Semiannually 
with 3 periods

```
    import math

    p = int(raw_input("what is the principal value?\n=> "))
    r = int(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
    c = int(raw_input("How many compoundings per periods are taking place? 
    \n=> "))
    t = int(raw_input("How mant periods are taking place?\n=>  "))

    number = str(p*(1+r/c)**c*t)
    print(number)
```

edit: sorry for crappy variables it is what is on my homework ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python input processing when input is a float or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144721/python-input-processing-when-input-is-a-float-or-string)

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you casting the input string as an `int` if you want a float?

Change

```py
r = int(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
```

to

```py
r = float(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
```

Answer (score 3):

No; that's a contradiction: an `int` does not have a decimal point.  `.052` is *not* an int; it's a float.  Use the proper conversion:

```
rate = float(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
```

Also, use meaningful variable names; single-letter variables tend to gang up and bite you later.