# is alpha and is digit in input questions

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, alpha

I'm creating a quiz game where if  a user types a number beyond a set amount or a word instead, it forces it to print an error message and go back to the start. I understand how to use the > than for the number, but have tried to use string, string == False, not alpha etc and keep getting the same error messages regarding int and string.

```
    while True:
        quiz=int(input("What answer do you think is right? Choose 1- 20"))
        if quiz >20:
            print("Oops, That's too high")
        else:
            print("Not a number")
            continue:
            break
```

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to check if input is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number)

Comment: You start quiz as a dictionary, then make it an int?

Comment: It's because after this I need to read data from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking that the string can actually be converted to an int, before typecasting your input to `int`.

You can use `isdigit` for this.

And you should be calling `.isalpha()` instead  of `isalpha`

Comment: I've read the links suggested, and made the changes.It doesn't work and I have the following error message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: What does that mean cast to an int?