# Python Boolean comparison

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm testing Python's Boolean expressions. When I run the following code:

```
x = 3
print type(x)
print (x is int)
print (x is not int)
```

I get the following results:

```
<type 'int'>
False
True
```

Why is (x is int) returning false and (x is not int) returning true when clearly x is an integer type?

Comment: `int` is a class. if you type just `int` you get `<class 'int'>`

Comment: `is` compares references. You want `isinstance(x,int)`

Comment: Python is not English. The `is` operator does something very specific, which appears to differ from what you expect.

Comment: `is` is not a Boolean operator, it's an identity operator

Comment: Take a look at this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator

Comment: you can also look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/python-how-to-check-if-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `is` you should do:

```
>>> print (type(x) is int)
True
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me understand Python's 'is' operator. I had read that 'is' could be used to check whether an identifier is of a specific type. Thank you coder for showing me the correct syntax for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is use `isinstance()`

so in your case:

```
x = 3
print isinstance(x, int)
```

Regarding python `is`

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: x is y is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object.

Taken from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

Answer (score 1):

Try typing these into your interpreter:

```
type(x)
int
x is 3
x is not 3
type(x) is int
type(x) is not int
```

The reason that `x is int` is false is that it is asking if the number `3` and the Python int class represent the same object. It should be fairly clear that this is false.

As a side note, Python's `is` keywords can work in some unexpected ways if you don't know exactly what it is doing, and you should almost certainly be avoiding it if you are ever testing equality. That being said, experimenting with it outside of your actual program is a very good idea.