# finding if a string doesn't have any integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code:

```
user_input = input('>>>: ')
if not re.search('[0-9]', user_input):
    print('That wasn\'t an integer.')
else:
    print('That was an integer!')
    print(user_input)
```

It basically tries to determine if the user's input is (mathematically) an integer or not. This works if the input is 'adgx'; the code recognizes that these aren't within the range 0-9, and print's 'That wasn't an integer.'. I need the program to print 'That wasn't an integer.' if the input is for example 'a3h1d', but it doesn't. I assume because the input technically contained numbers that were within the range, it satisfied the statement. I need it so that if the input is 'a3h1d' that the program prints 'That wasn't an integer.'.

Comment: what do you think `re.search` does?

Comment: `user_input.isdigit()`

Comment: Why not just `try: int(user_input)`, then catch the error?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Comment: If you want to accept negative numbers, use `int(user_input)` and catch the error. If only positive integers, use `user_input.isdigit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `re.match()` plus the beginning-of-string and end-of-string markers:

```
user_input = input('>>>: ')
if not re.match('^[0-9]+$', user_input):
    print('That wasn\'t an integer.')
else:
    print('That was an integer!')
```

Remember that, in regex:

- `^` Matches the start of a line;
- `$` Matches the end of a line;
- `+` Indicates that the previous pattern should appear one or more times.

I would recommend taking a look at [Python official 're' documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for a more complete and well explained list.

Comment: Should be `r'^[0-9]+$'`, otherwise it only matches a single digit.

Comment: Very true; I missed that detail. :P

Comment: Could you explain the metacharacters and what they're doing? I'm still learning regex

Comment: Okay, added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't tied to the idea of using a regex for this, I would suggest simply using [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

```
user_input = input('>>>: ')
if not user_input.isdigit():
    print('That wasn\'t an integer.')
else:
    print('That was an integer!')
```

There's also this approach

```
try:
    user_input = int(input('>>>: '))
    print('That was an integer!')
except ValueError:
    print('That wasn\'t an integer.')
```

Comment: I can't use try, because though i know i didn't include it but i have now after editing, because then it will convert '00000000' to '0' when i need to print it