# How to make a bar table using pygal with string records.?

Tags: python, pygal

I am creating table using [pygal](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/table.html#default), the example in the [link](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/table.html#default) works well, 
but I did the below change in it.

```
line_chart = pygal.Bar()
line_chart.title = 'Browser usage evolution (in %)'
line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))
line_chart.add('Firefox', ["Hello", 'world', 'aaa', 'bbbb',   'ccc',   'cccc', 'dddd', 'eee', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh'])
line_chart.add('Chrome',  [None, None, None, None, None, None,    0,  3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3])
line_chart.add('IE',      [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5,   66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1])
line_chart.add('Others',  [14.2, 15.4, 15.3,  8.9,    9, 10.4,  8.9,  5.8,  6.7,  6.8,  7.5])
line_chart.value_formatter = lambda x: '%.2f%%' % x if x is not None else '∅'
line_chart.render_table(style=True)
```

for the Firefox column I am adding string values in the list, it is giving me error like:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

How can I include string records in the pygal table?

Answer (score 0):

To understand your issue you're going to need to understand this line:

```
line_chart.value_formatter = lambda x: '%.2f%%' % x if x is not None else '∅'
```

what pygal is doing here is taking in a function to apply to each table value in order to get a string value out to be put into the actual table.   In this case the formatter takes in a number (int or float) and uses the older formatting syntax for formatting. `'%.2f%%' % x basically` says "I'm going to put x here, modify the string representation such that it forces at least two decimal places, and then add a '%' symbol to the end".  Additionally this lambda function checks if the value is not `None` before doing this, because formatting the string value in this way wouldn't work with a None value since it isn't a number, and outputs that  null character.

In the original example, all table values where numerical values.   Once you replaced the firefox column/row with string values the formatter couldn't work.   Your error comes from the function   `lambda x: '%.2f%%' % x if x is not None else '∅'` not being able to be applied to string values.  In order to fix this you can either A: change the formatter to accept string values or B: change the values in firefox to use numbers instead of strings.

You wanted String records, so to change this you can add a check for type (ie using `type(value) == int`) or if you also want to use string integers, try a conversion first (ie `int(value)` or `float(value)`).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number) for more details on int checking for strings.

Your formatter lambda function might for example become:

```
lambda x: '%.2f%%' % x if type(x) is int or type(x) is float else '∅'
```

if you want to do something like the conversion checker, you are going to have to try: catch: it, so you'll need to make an actual formatter function instead of a lambda.