# How do I avoid error while using int()?

Tags: python

I have a question concerning `int()`. Part of my Python codes looks like this

```
string = input('Enter your number:')
n = int(string)
print n
```

So if the input string of `int()` is not a number, Python will report ValueError and stop running the remaining codes.

I wonder if there is a way to make the program re-ask for a valid string? So that the program won't just stop there.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is

## Try / Except

**How it works:**

```
try:
    # Code to "try".
except:
    # If there's an error, trap the exception and continue.
    continue
```

**For your scenario:**

```
def GetInput():
    try:
        string = input('Enter your number:') 
        n = int(string) 
        print n
    except:
        # Try to get input again.
        GetInput()
```

Comment: This `GetInput` function does not return anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try except`

```
while True:
    try:
        string = input('Enter your number:')
        n = int(string)
        print n
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: You are missing a `break` somewhere :p

Comment: You are missing a `:` too. Also, you should try to avoid infinite while loops and give them a clever condition instead.

Comment: Updated. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole thing in an infinite loop. You should catch and ignore `ValueError`s but break out of the loop when you get a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = None
while not isinstance(n, int):
    try:
        n = int(input('Enter your number:'))
    except:
        print('NAN')
```

Comment: You are catching a very broad exception. Somehow input console is corrupted that will stuck in a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

While the others have mentioned that you can use the following method,

```
try :
except :
```

This is another way to do the same thing.

```
while True : 
    string = input('Enter your number:')
    if string.isdigit() : 
        n = int(string)
        print n
        break
     else : 
        print("You have not entered a valid number. Re-enter the number")
```

You can learn more about 
  [Built-in String Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) from here.