# How to check if the input string is an integer

Tags: string, python-3.x, int

```
if input()==int():
    print('mission successful!')
else:
    print('mission failed!')
```

for above code the problem is, that it never results in `mission successful` even though my input is integer.

I have just started learning python.

Comment: It's important to know that `input()` will not give you an integer, but a string, even if you input a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if the input string is numeric, you can use this:

```
s = input()
if s.isnumeric() or (s.startswith('-') and s[1:].isdigit()):
    print('mission successful!')
else:
    print('mission failed!')
```

In Python, checking if a string equals a number will always return `False`. In order to compare strings and numbers, it helps to either convert the string to a number or the number to a string first. For example:

```
>>> "1" == 1
False
>>> int("1") == 1
True
```

or

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
>>> str(1) == "1"
True
```

If a string can not be converted to a number with `int`, a `ValueError` will be thrown. You can catch it like this:

```
try:
    int("asdf")
except ValueError:
    print("asdf is not an integer")
```

Comment: First method fails for negative ints or floats