# Python: I have nested for loops that aren't working and I don't know why

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

So I'm trying to figure out how to print numbers that have more even digits than odd digits. This is my code:

```
inVal=(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
evencounter=0
oddcounter=0

for i in range(1,int(inVal)):
    for j in range (1,len(str(i))):
        if(int(str(i)[j])%2==0):
            evencounter+=1
        else:
            oddcounter+=1
    if(evencounter>oddcounter):
        print(i)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is, you haven't reset your counter variables. Another problem is that your second loop starts from 1 instead of 0. (thanks Leonardo Gazdek for pointing out!)

Strings indexes start from 0:

```
>>> 'abc'[1]
'b'
```

Here's how you should do it:

```
inVal=(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
evencounter=0
oddcounter=0

for i in range(1,int(inVal)):
    # add those pieces of code:
    evencounter=0 
    oddcounter=0
    for j in range (0,len(str(i))): # start from 0
        if(int(str(i)[j])%2==0):
            evencounter+=1
        else:
            oddcounter+=1
    if(evencounter>oddcounter):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

As zeet correctly pointed out, you need to reset the counters on each number (they don't even need to be global), but you have another issue. You need to start the second loop from 0, not 1. String indexes start from 0.

```
inVal=(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))

for i in range(1,int(inVal)):
    evencounter=0 
    oddcounter=0
    for j in range (0,len(str(i))):
        if(int(str(i)[j])%2==0):
            evencounter+=1
        else:
            oddcounter+=1
    if(evencounter>oddcounter):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) gives values from `start` till values *less than* `stop`.

In your inner loop, change

```
for j in range (1,len(str(i))):
```

to

```
for j in range (0,len(str(i))):
```

since the indexing starts from `0`.

And you need to reset the value of the counter after each iteration of the outer loop so that it can start over for the next number.

Also, if you want to include `inVal` as well, change the outer loop to

```
for i in range(1,int(inVal)+1):
```

You might also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number) out for exception handling in case the user's input is not a number.

```
evencounter=0
oddcounter=0

try:
    for i in range(1,int(inVal)+1):
        for j in range (0,len(str(i))):
            if(int(str(i)[j])%2==0):
                evencounter+=1
            else:
                oddcounter+=1
        if(evencounter>oddcounter):
            print(i)

        oddcounter = evencounter = 0
except ValueError:
    print('Conversion error!')
```