# How do I omit strings and other characters within conditionals in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a small code that asks a user to enter a number between 1 and 100. However my Else statement will not output when entering a string. I want my Else statement to print a message if the user enters an input other than an integer or float. Here is my code.

```
def between():
    print ("Please enter a number between 1 and 100.")
    number = eval(input())
    if number >= 1 and number <= 100:
        print ("Thank you! You entered",number,"which is within the 1 and 100 range.")
        between()
    elif number > 100 or number < 1: 
        print ("OOPS! You entered",number,"Please enter a number between 1 and 100.")
        between()
    else: 
        print ("ERROR! You have entered an invalid value. Please try again using numerical values only.")
        between()

between()
```

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to use `try` and `except`

```
num = input()
try:
    number = float(num)
    # code to do if num is a number
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number!")
    # code to do if num isn't a number
```

If `num` isn't a number, then converting it to a float would raise `ValueError` going on to the `except`.
If `num` is a number, the coversion of it to a float would run fine, and continue on in the `try`.

Side note: I highly suggest not using `eval(input())` but rather just `input()`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/9356457) for why you shouldn't use `eval`. Also `eval(input())` won't work with my example above.

Comment: The easiest way is not the try, that is like using brute force, there are built-in methods to check whether an object is of a class or another (In python everything is a object even the functions)

Comment: @ShadyCake I used eval because it could automatically detect whether the input was an int or a float. I wanted to make the code universal to both.

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz input will always return a string, what I am doing is checking if the string can be converted into an integer. Not checking if the variable itself is an integer.

Comment: @Zach Using float() to convert it will have the same effect you are looking for, but without the dangers of eval()

Comment: In that case make use of isdigit() ;) try is not necessary at all.
Not trying to promote myself tho.
@ShadyCake look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088022/7579116

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz The only problem with isdigit() is that is doesn't work for floats, and Zach has said that they wants it to work for floats also.

Comment: @ShadyCake You are right, the only way it would work, will be something like num.replace('.','').isdigit().

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz That is a good workaround, I'd suggest mentioning that in your answer.

Comment: Updated. Good discussion tho.

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz Yeah it was, but I think you meant to put .replace(',', '') instead of .replace('.', '') in your answer. Also I realised that this wouldnt work if you put in a string with multiple dots, eg 1.2.3.

Comment: oh It will work, as replace doesn't stop in the first match. it's global replacement

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz No, I mean that 1.2.3, with dots removed, will return true for isdigit(), even when 1.2.3 can't be converted to a float. So the script would raise a ValueError

Comment: Now I get watch you said, so it might end up getting more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print "Please enter a number between 1 and 100"
in = input()


try:
    num = int(in)

    if 1 <= num <= 100:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Out of bounds")

except:

    print("Invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def between():
    print ("Please enter a number between 1 and 100.")
    number=0
    try:
        number = int(input())
    except:
        print ("ERROR! You have entered an invalid value. Please try again using numerical values only.")
        exit(1)
    if number >= 1 and number <= 100:
        print ("Thank you! You entered",number,"which is within the 1 and 100 range.")
        between()
    else: 
        print ("OOPS! You entered",number,"Please enter a number between 1 and 100.")
        between()


 between()
```

Note: why you use eval and input together? I don't think that's right, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Evals are a really bad practice!, someone could pass anything there! https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/7579116

Answer (score 0):

Try is too slow and should be avoided when not necessary

```
num = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 100: ")

if num.replace('.','').isdigit():
    num = float(num)
    if number >= 1 and number <= 100:
        print ("Thank you! You entered",number,"which is within the 1 and 100 range.")
        between()
    else:
        print ("OOPS! You entered",number,"Please enter a number between 1 and 100.")
        between()
else:
    print('thats not a number!')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few logical issues with your code. First before using `eval()` you must be aware of the security risk associated with it. Consider going through this [post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) for some insight. If you entered some arbitrary input in eval, it will most likely be a run time error.

Now, assuming that the variable actually has a value. To check if it is an integer or a float and is in the desired range or something else (possibly a string), you can not directly apply comparison operators with it because if the variable is not a number it will most likely give a `TypeError` during comparison with other integers.

Hence a correct approach would be to first check if the variable is of desired type by checking `if type(r) is int or type(r) is float` only then you should apply test for range. If the above type checking is false then you should print your "else" error message.