# Python automatically converts to text

Tags: python, types

I want to get the output if the input value type is "Int" then print this message "please enter the string not integer" else calling the function.

It seems Python automatically takes the value type as "String". But I want to get the message like I mentioned if enter type. Please check the below code.

```
def strlength (string):
    lengthstring = len(string)
    return (lengthstring)

string = input("enter the string: ")
if type(string) == int:
    print("please enter the string not integer")
else:
    print(strlength(string))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems Python automatically takes the value type as "String"

No. The value type **is** string, until you convert it to something else. There is no secret magic that guesses possible variable types from the user's input.

There is a [helper function `isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) you can use to check if a string only consists of digits.

```
response = input("enter the string: ")

if str.isdigit(response):
    ...
```

Comment: This check would fail for a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

this is your solution

```
 def strlength (string):
    lengthstring = len(string)
    return (lengthstring)

string = input("enter the string: ")

try:
    string = int(string)
    print("please enter the string not integer")
except :
    print(strlength(string))
```