# Making sure the user's input is not a string in Python 3

Tags: python

I try to make a function that  at first will check if the input is not a string.
But if the user inputs a float, it gets False.
I need it to accept both Int and Float, bot not a string.

```
def squat():
    value = input("What is your RM1?")

    if value.isnumeric():
        rm1 = float(value)
        print("Your RM1 is: ", rm1)
        print(type(value))

    else:
        print("Error")


squat()
```

Comment: `input` always returns a string

Comment: Did you mean to ask a way to determine if the users input was a _numerical_ string? If so you can refer to an existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `try..except` block in your case

```
def squat():
    value = input("What is your RM1?")
    try:
         rm1 = float(value)
    except ValueError:
         print("error")
         exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function always returns a *string*. You can use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to check if the string looks like number:

```
import re

value = input('What is your RM1? ')
if re.match(r'^\d+(\.\d+)?$', value):
    rm1 = float(value)
    print('Your RM1 is: ', rm1)
else:
    print('Error')
```