# How to make a user input specific data type in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm writing a basic program which is to create a team based on age groups. So I want to create a team, but for example for the first team they have to be between the age of 20 and 25:

```
while True:
        if(num<20):
            num = int(input("Too young, try again!: "))
        elif(num>25):
            num = int(input("Too old, try again!: "))
```

I also want to display a message in the if statement if the user enters text rather than an integer, for example:

```
elif(num is not int):
    num = int(input("Please enter integers(numbers)only!: ")
```

I'm new to Python so sorry if the example is poor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for try/except [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```py
try:
    value = int(input(...))
except ValueError:
    # handle Exception
```

this works because `int()` raises `ValueError` on non-int inputs

```py
>>> int("not an integer")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not an integer'
>>> int("5")
5
```

Answer (score 0):

would recomend try or except

```
try:
   value = int(input(...))
execpt:
  print("intiger please")
```