# How do i stop my code from outputting negative numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game of last man standing in python, but when you input a number it outputs the negative version of the correct answer? Also, when i enter anything other than 1, 2, or 3, I get the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(anything other than the numbers)'

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import random

num = random.randrange(20, 30)  
print ("The number is " + str(num) + ", take either one, two or three away from it!")
take = float(input("input either 1, 2 or 3: "))
newnum = take - num
if take == 1:
    print(newnum)
elif take == 2:
    print(newnum)
elif take == 3:
    print(newnum)
else:
    print("please enter either 1, 2 or 3!")
```

Comment: Any number in range `20 .. 30` will be greater than `1`, `2` or `3`.

Comment: Did you mean `num - take`?

Comment: im so stupid! my bad on the first part, has anyone got a fix for the value error bit?

Comment: And, second problem (input validation)> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a while loop to make sure the user only inputs 1,2 or 3.

```
import random

num = random.randrange(20, 30)  
print ("The number is " + str(num) + ", take either one, two or three away from it!")
take = None
while take not in {1,2,3}: #{} faster than ()
    take = int(input("input either 1, 2 or 3: "))
    print("please enter either 1, 2 or 3!")
print(num-take)
```

Also as the above code shows, you need to use `num-take` instead of vice-versa.

Comment: `1 <= take <= 3` should be slightly faster, but if you want to use `in` then use *set* as a container, it'd be a bit faster `take not in {1, 2, 3}`. For huge ranges more efficient will be to use conditional check *(first option)* or `range()`: `if take not in range(1, 4)`.

Comment: Thank you for that, never new about this.