# I don't know why guessNum and secretNum don't do the While comparison right?

Tags: python

I don't get the correct answer, it goes into an infinite loop, it doesn't recognize when I enter the number 7, it goes into the loop anyway

```
guessNum=input("please, give your guess number: ")
secretNum=7

while not guessNum == secretNum:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    print("wrong number: ",guessNum)
    guessNum=input("please, give your guess number: ")

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Comment: you are comparing a string against a number (add `int(input(...))` to cast string to int)

Comment: `input` always returns a string, so `guessNum` is a string, not a number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the type mismatch of comparing a `str` value from `input` to an `int` value, you should prefer `a != b` over `not a == b`, and structure the loop so that you only need *one* assignment to `guessNum`:

```
secretNum = 7

while True:
    guessNum = int(input("please, give your guess number: "))
    if guessNum == secretNum:
        break

    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    print("wrong number: ", guessNum)

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

or

```
secretNum = 7
while (guessNum := int(input("please, give your guess number: "))) != secretNum:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    print("wrong number: ", guessNum)

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guessNum=int(input("please, give your guess number: "))
secretNum=7

while not guessNum == secretNum:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    print("wrong number: ",guessNum)
    guessNum=int(input("please, give your guess number: "))

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

add the int before input

Comment: Great thank you so much… I don’t see that