# .removeprefix() method on a string does nothing

Tags: python

Upon entering an input, say $50.00, I get an error that says `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$50.00'`. I already have `dollars.removeprefix("$")` in line 10, the .removeprefix() method simply does nothing. What am I doing wrong? Full code below:

```
def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    percent = percent / 100
    tip = dollars * percent
    print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")


def dollars_to_float(dollars):
    dollars.removeprefix("$")
    return float(dollars)


def percent_to_float(percent):
    percent.removesuffix("%")
    return float(percent)


main()
```

Comment: Save the result to a variable.

Comment: Your script works fine adding only numbers and ignoring the currencty, but I'd go with this - force a numeric input. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reassigning your result to a variable.

```
def main():
    dollars = dollars_to_float(input("How much was the meal? "))
    percent = percent_to_float(input("What percentage would you like to tip? "))
    percent = percent / 100
    tip = dollars * percent
    print(f"Leave ${tip:.2f}")


def dollars_to_float(dollars):
    dollars = dollars.removeprefix("$")
    return float(dollars)


def percent_to_float(percent):
    percent = percent.removesuffix("%")
    return float(percent)
```

You should really improve your code to perform some more input validation. What happens to your script if I do this?

```
>>> How much was the meal? 
>>> 50$
```

A simple idea to make it more robust:

```
import re

def dollars_to_float(dollars):
    # Extract numbers, ignore all else
    dollars = re.sub(r"[^1-9\.]", "", dollars)
    return float(dollars)
```

Comment: If I type in £34, the code errors - there's nowhere to say what currency. 
If I type 34, the code works fine.

Comment: Exactly, there should be some more input validation. I'll add a few ideas to my answer

Comment: That was it. Oops