# Break in Condition

Tags: python

The user is supposed to enter a number from 1 to 10 and the code is supposed to check for 3 conditions
if the input is not a number ask for entering again, if the input is out of 1-10 ask for entering again, and if the number is in range of 1-10 break the loop and store the value in the variable. the first two checks are running correctly, but the last is not working, the loop does not break, and it says invalid input like other conditions. What is the problem?

```
 while True:
        num_guess = input("How many times you want to guess [1-10]: ") # Asking for number of guess
        if num_guess != int: # Checking for non number input
            print("Invalid input")
        elif int(num_guess) < 1 or int(num_guess) > 10: # Checking for out of range input
            print("Invalid input")
        elif 1 <= int(num_guess) <= 10: # if input is in the range just break the loop and store the answer
            break
```

Answer (score 3):

`if num_guess != int` should be:

```
try:
    num_guess = int(num_guess)
except ValueError:
    print("Not a number!")
    continue
```

Reference: [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` method takes you input and converts it into a string input. So even if you enter number 12, the input will converted to “12” and stored in `num_guess`. So, the best way to check if the input is a number or not, is using the `isdigit()` method.

So the line 3 of your code should be written as

```
if not num_guess.isdigit():
```

Comment: "By default"? So there is a way to make input() return something other than a string?

Comment: If you look at the return type of `input()` it returns a string, so it is up to you to type cast it into int or float or anything like `int(input())` or `float(input())`

Comment: Yeah, I know that. The why do you claim that `input()` only returns a string "by default"?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

By the text “by default” I meant it only returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if not num_guess.isnumeric()` to check if all the characters of the string are numeric characters.
`num_guess` is always a String, so answers suggestion to check the type are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why it keeps saying "Invalid input" it's because **num_guess** is always a string.

You can try it this way, I hope this helps.

```
# store input result
result: int

while True:
    num_guess = input(">> How many times you want to guess [1-10]: ") # Asking for number of guess

    try:
        int(num_guess) # raise ValueError if num_guess is NaN
    except ValueError:
        print(">> Interger 1 ... 10 required.")

    if int(num_guess) < 1 or int(num_guess) > 10: # Checking for out of range input
        print(">> Interger from 1 to 10 required.")
    elif 1 <= int(num_guess) <= 10: # if input is in the range just break the loop and store the answer
        # store the value in the result variable
        result = int(num_guess)
        print(">> Saving...")
        break
```

Comment: There's no sense repeatedly calling `int(num_guess)`. Call it once and save the result if no exception is raise. (And put less code in the `try` statement; the only thing that belongs there is the attempt to call `int`, not the following `if` statement.)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `if num_guess != int` with `if type(num_guess) != int`.
This is because you need to check what data type the number is, using an equality operator with `int` would try to check if the object is the [class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) `int`.

In python everything is an object (or a data type), even the constructors for objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if input is a number you must get type of the variable using `type(YOUR_VARIABLE)` so python would check the type of it returning values like: "int", "str", "float" and by that way you can check if variable is an int!

or just don't read it and steal this code:

```
 while True:
        num_guess = input("How many times you want to guess [1-10]: ") # Asking for number of guess
        if type(num_guess) != int: # Checking for non number input
            print("Invalid input")
        elif int(num_guess) < 1 or int(num_guess) > 10: # Checking for out of range input
            print("Invalid input")
        elif 1 <= int(num_guess) <= 10: # if input is in the range just break the loop and store the answer
            break
```

but im still not 100% sure so you can check it and correct me if I did something wrong

Comment: `num_guess` will *never* be an `int`, since `input` always returns `str` values.