# trying to make a number guessing game and its not working

Tags: python

```
saldo = str("1000")#how much money you have
bet = input("kuinka paljon rahaa laitat peliin: ")#how much do you want to bet

while True:
    if bet == str():
        print("täytyy olla numero")#needs to be a number
    else:
        break
```

I expect it to break.

Comment: And what do you reckon  `if bet == str()` does?

Comment: Shuld be `if bet == saldo:`

Comment: `input` will always return a `str` instance unless you convert it to something else. To check if something is a `str` use `isinstance(bet, str)` but in this case that is always true since you never use the `int` or `float` functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-can-i-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

```
class str(object)
    ...
    Create a new string object from the given object.
```

Meaning

```
if bet == str():
```

Will check `bet` against the result of `str()` which is an empty string. Also, using `input` will always give you a string, so there is no need to check whether it is a string. If you enter `1` for instance, you will get the string `"1"`. If you want to verify the user input was indeed a number, you'll need other checks, for instance:

```
import string
foo = input('foo: ')
if not foo in string.digits:
   ...
```

or

```
foo = input('foo: ')
try:
    bar = int(foo)
except ValueError:
    print("This wasn't a number.")
```

You'll likely want to put your `input` in your loop as well, if I understand your intentions correctly. For instance:

```
saldo = 1000
while True:
    bet = input('bet: ')
    try:
        foo = int(bet)
        break
    except:
        print("This wasn't a number, try again.")
```